# Is using std::set<myOwnObjectType> a source of problems?

Tags: c++

I've had several programs I made in which the compiler didn't flag any errors when I wrote `std::set` with my own objects but as soon as I attempted to build the program I got some error that seemed to be pointing to some implementation file for `std::set`. For example, in my program right now the compiler is pointing to the line

```
struct _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY less : binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool>
{
    _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_AFTER_CXX11 _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY 
    bool operator()(const _Tp& __x, const _Tp& __y) const
        {return __x < __y;} // <---- That's the problem line
};
```

with the error

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('const XMLNode' and 'const XMLNode')
```

and that traces back to the line

```
std::set<XMLNode> children;
```

in my code. Is my assumption correct that the program is confused because it doesn't know how to compare `XMLNode` elements? If so, what is a data structure I can use similar to `std::set` except that it's equipped to hold any type of element? I want something that holds objects of the same type without any repeats and preferably with fast access.

Comment: The whole point of writing your own comparison functor is that your code should know how to make a meaningful comparison between two objects. You could try `unordered_set` but for that you need to write a hashing function.

Comment: It is saying that you need to implement the less than (`<`) operator for your class, or provide an object that can carry out the comparison - a functor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trees (the underlying structure of a set) rely on being able to compare objects so as to decide in which branch to insert them and, in the end, provide O(log n) accesses.

Therefore, if you want to use `std::set`, your type needs to provide a way to compare objects - either through `operator <`, an implementation of `std::less<XMLNode>`, or by passing your comparer when declaring the set through `Compare`, its first template argument.

If the concept of comparison does not apply to XMLNode, then you may be interested in either making up an artificial comparison criterion, or using `std::unordered_set` (which offers amortized O(1) accesses) and providing an implementation for `std::hash<XMLNode>`.